# Implementing Tarjan's strongly connected components without relying on potential failure as an effect

Tags: algorithm, reference, graph-algorithm

I am trying to implement graph algorithms in Standard ML, under the constraint that the only allowed effect is mutating reference cells. Exceptions and nontermination are forbidden. Standard ML itself is inessential to the question. I will accept an answer in any other typed programming language so long as it satisfies my constraint. (Unfortunately, untyped languages are out: checking the well-formedness of the data and potentially failing is in itself the effect I want to avoid.)

I will illustrate how one can program under my constraint by implementing Kosaraju's algorithm. My question is whether Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm can also be implemented in this style.

```
datatype 'a node = Node of 'a * bool ref * 'a node list ref * 'a node list ref

fun node x = Node (x, ref false, ref nil, ref nil)
fun mark (Node (_, r, _, _)) = !r before r := true
fun unmark (Node (_, r, _, _)) = !r before r := false

fun value (Node (x, _, _, _)) = x
fun sources (Node (_, _, ref xs, _)) = xs
fun targets (Node (_, _, _, ref ys)) = ys

fun connect (m, n) =
  let
    val Node (_, _, _, ns) = m
    val Node (_, _, ms, _) = n
  in
    ms := m :: !ms;
    ns := n :: !ns
  end

datatype 'a state = Root of 'a node | Children of 'a node list

fun visit (xs, nil) = xs
  | visit (xs, Root x :: ss) = visit (x :: xs, ss)
  | visit (xs, Children nil :: ss) = visit (xs, ss)
  | visit (xs, Children (y :: ys) :: ss) =
    if mark y then
      visit (xs, Children ys :: ss)
    else
      visit (xs, Children (targets y) :: Root y :: Children ys :: ss)

fun assign (xs, nil) = xs
  | assign (xs, nil :: ss) = assign (xs, ss)
  | assign (xs, (x :: s) :: ss) =
    if unmark x then
      assign (x :: xs, sources x :: s :: ss)
    else
      assign (xs, s :: ss)

fun assigns (xs, nil) = xs
  | assigns (xs, y :: ys) =
    case assign (nil, (y :: nil) :: nil) of
        nil => assigns (xs, ys)
      | x => assigns (x :: xs, ys)

fun kosaraju xs = assigns (nil, visit (nil, Children xs :: nil))
```

Is it possible to implement Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm in this style?

Answer (score 1):

I have an open source project over here that produces discrete finite automata: https://github.com/mtimmerm/dfalex

It includes an implementation of Tarjan's algorithm in a style that is somewhat similar to what you want, but the DFS function takes 3 lambdas:

```
   /**
     * Perform a depth first search of all states, starting at the start states
     * <P>
     * To avoid stack overflow errors on large DFAs, the implementation uses an auxiliary
     * stack on the heap instead of recursing
     * 
     * @param onEnter  called with (parent, child) when a child is entered.  parent == null for roots.
     * @param onSkip  called with (parent, child) when a child is skipped because it has been entered
     *                  previously.  parent == null for roots.
     * @param onLeave  called with (parent, child) when a child is exited.  parent == null for roots.
     */
    public void depthFirstSearch(
            BiConsumer<DfaState<MATCHRESULT>, DfaState<MATCHRESULT>> onEnter,
            BiConsumer<DfaState<MATCHRESULT>, DfaState<MATCHRESULT>> onSkip,
            BiConsumer<DfaState<MATCHRESULT>, DfaState<MATCHRESULT>> onLeave)
    {
```

Tarjan's algorithm is in this file on line 200, a method call "getCycleNumbers":

https://github.com/mtimmerm/dfalex/blob/master/src/com/nobigsoftware/dfalex/DfaAuxiliaryInformation.java#L200

Your definition of a visitor doesn't support all of these 3 different kinds of events.  It only provides "onEnter".  They're all required for Tarjan's algorithm.  It *is* possible to reconstitute them from what you do get, but it would be more complicated than just writing a new DFS that provides all 3.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the reference.

Comment: The following line doesn't throw an exception: https://github.com/mtimmerm/dfalex/blob/master/src/com/nobigsoftware/dfalex/DfaAuxiliaryInformation.java#L246 , but you cannot prove it with either Java or ML's type system.

Comment: Hence, because Java is memory safe, it needs to perform a check that the stack is nonempty, even though you know this in advance. It is this very check that I want to figure out how to elide.

Comment: You could do the check yourself instead, and turn for (;;) into while (!stack.isEmpty).   You can't capture the emptiness of that stack with a type, because that would imply a different type for each size, and the size is unbounded.